# Problema en la invocación de una ventana modal en una imagen en Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, modal, bootstrap-4

Quiero que al dar click en una imagen x esta se muestre con una ventana modal.
Tengo este código en Bootstrap 4:

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <!--            seccion portafolio-->
        <div class="row portafolio">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 class="titulo">Portafolio</h2>
                <div class="row galeria justify-content-center">
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/900x232" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/900x232" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-12 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <img src="" id="imagen-modal">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

No le coloqué la ruta de la imagen porque es relativa, por eso tengo este script de JQuery que me devuelve la ruta de la imagen seleccionada para así mostrarla. Este es el código:

```
$(function () {
$('.galeria .contenedor-imagen').on('click', function(){
    $('#modal').modal;
    var ruta_imagen = ($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('#imagen-modal').attr('src', ruta_imagen);
});

$('#modal').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
});
```

})

El problema viene que al dar click no me lo está mostrando, es decir, no me muestra la ventana modal. Me parece que el error está en el modal de Bootstrap pero no logro dar con la falla.

Answer (score 0):

Funciona:

```js
$(function () {
$('.galeria .contenedor-imagen').on('click', function(){
    $('#modal').modal;
    var ruta_imagen = ($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('#imagen-modal').attr('src', ruta_imagen);
});

$('#modal').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <!--            seccion portafolio-->
        <div class="row portafolio">
            <div class="col">
                <h2 class="titulo">Portafolio</h2>
                <div class="row galeria justify-content-center">
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/900x232" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/900x232" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-12 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contenedor-imagen col-6 col-lg-4">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/700x393" class="img-fluid imagen" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <img src="" id="imagen-modal">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: conchale a mi no me sale @LuisFernando

Comment: ninguno solo que no me muestra en el navegador la ventana modal @LuisFernando

Comment: en la consola no muestra nada de error es extrano @LuisFernando

Comment: el script funciona porque veo que me coloca la ruta en el atributo src @LuisFernando

Comment: si me funciona que sera que pasa?@LuisFernando

Comment: el script lo invoco de ultimo y así <script src="js/scripts.js"></script> pero bueno no se que mas puede ser @LuisFernando

Comment: ya lo solucione, tenia una versión inestable de bootstrap @LuisFernando